# Рассчитать разницу во времени

Tags: php

Изначально есть время в формате 2018-02-08 13:26:03 (как пример).

Нужно рассчитать прошло ли 2 часа между текущим временем и указанным.

Как это можно просто сделать в PHP? Переводить в UNIX-формат текущее, из которого вычесть 2 часа, и указанное и использовать условие?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.diff.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используем [`date_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.diff.php).

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2018-02-08 13:54:00');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2018-02-08 15:52:00');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);

$diff = $interval->format('%h') * 3600 + $interval->format('%i') * 60 + $interval->format('%s');

echo $diff > 7200 ? 'Прошло больше 2 часов' : 'Менее 2 часов';
```

**Результат:** Менее **2** часов, так как будет **1 час 58 минут**.

Comment: А можно как-то выяснить разницу во времени именно в меньшую сторону?

Comment: @TimurMusharapov, в каком смысле? Имеете ввиду даты местами поменять?