# Расчет разницы между датами

Tags: php

Сравниваю две даты (одна из базы данных $item['online'], а вторая текущая date('H:i:s d.m.Y')).

```
<?php
    $datetime1 = new DateTime($item['online']);
    $datetime2 = new DateTime(date('H:i:s d.m.Y'));
    $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
    $interval->format('%i%a');
?>
```

Вопрос заключается в том, что в новом часу все обнуляется. А нужно сравнить две даты и если разница между ними к примеру более 10 минут, то к примеру выдать сообщение echo "Разница дат более 10 минут";. Но ввиду обнуления каждый час сделать это не получается.

Comment: Возможно это поможет: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/782133/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8/782157#782157

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простой пример, даты в unix формате

```
$current_time = time();
$old_time = $item['time'];
$difference_time = ($current_time - $old_time);


if ($difference_time >= 600) {
    echo date('H:i:s d.m.Y', $difference_time);
}
```

Comment: Вроде как получилось, но походу возник еще один вопрос, как после данное значение представить в необходимом визуальном формате, что то вроде date('H:i:s d.m.Y')?

Comment: отредактировал пост, смотрите

Comment: $difference_time - это разница в секундах, можете в любой формате перевести